# Secure client side env variables in Next JS

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I am worried that my Keys for various functions are exposed to the client. I have this function

```
onRunOCR = async (event) => {
   const client = new SomeAPI({
     credentials: {
       accessKeyId: 'ffg23f23f23f32f23',
       secretAccessKey: 'GZMIKGDoISDGpsgjMIPSGMDIPG',
     },
   })
}
```

This is basically an on click function in my class component. This is fully exposed to anyone right?
How can I secure it. Would `NEXT_PUBLIC_ACCESS_KEY` work or is that the same just stores it as a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, keys are exposed in your example.

Anyone can access private keys that are exposed to the browser. The most common way to prevent key leakage is only to use them server-side.

You can create an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) or a custom endpoint like an AWS Lambda function that you call in your `onClick` handler.

Using [env variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) in your server-side function is okay as they are never rendered to the browser.

.env file

```
API_KEY_ID=123456
API_ACCESS_KEY=ABCDEF
```

API route

```js
export default function handler(_, res) {
  const data = new SomeAPI({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.API_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.API_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
  })
  res.status(200).json(data)
}
```

Other default Next.js server-side features/functions it's okay to place keys are [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props), [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths), and [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware).